# a void sender to xib ( objective c - ios )

Tags: ios, objective-c

i created a new project , all files in .h + .m ,,

and i want add xib to the project , i did every thing still the way of sender code ,,

see here the xib.h file :-

http://joxi.ru/8AnVEaNSqxeYbA.jpg

and here the xib.m

http://joxi.ru/Vm67ZK3uxqPya2.jpg

so now i have other view.m want to send to the xib

i use this way :-

```
-(void)addPlace {
AddPlaceController *placeController = [[AddPlaceController alloc] init];
[placeController setThemeColor:[[_configDictionary objectForKey:@"appearance"] objectForKey:@"mainColor"]];
[placeController setConfigDictionary:_configDictionary];
[placeController setUserLocation:_userLocation];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:placeController];
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[ColorUtil colorFromHexString:[[_configDictionary objectForKey:@"appearance"] objectForKey:@"navigationBarTextColor"] withAlpha:0.8],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0],NSFontAttributeName,nil]];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];}
```

But the app not send me to xib

thank u

Comment: Do not post the screenshots of your code, copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the your xib's view is connected with file's owner or not. I think this will be the issue.

Comment: exactly , thank you so much ,, that is my issue i forgot to connect the xib's thank you so so so much

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't initialize the view controller with the nib file.

So, instead of `AddPlaceController *placeController = [[AddPlaceController alloc] init];` use `AddPlaceController *placeController = [[AddPlaceController alloc] initWithNibName:@"XIB_NAME" bundle:nil];`. If you have your xib file inside any bundle, in the `bundle` part of the initialization method you should pass the name of the bundle. Good Luck!